# Is it possible to prevent Cypress from waiting for the server?

Tags: cypress

I need to start the server inside the tests. I have read the advice at https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Web-Servers, and I still need to start the server inside the tests (and possibly restart it mid-test). If I try to do that, I get the error "Cypress could not verify that this server is running:" and as far as I can see it never even tries to run the `beforeEach` that would start it. Is it possible to bypass that behaviour?

Comment: Did you try not setting `baseUrl`? Could you expand on why you need to start the server _inside_ the tests?

Comment: Not setting baseURL (and putting the full URL in cy.visit) seems to work. If you want to put that in an answer I'll give it the tick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware that's not exactly configurable, but you *can* leave out the `baseUrl` entirely. If Cypress doesn't know where your app is running, it won't do any pre-test polling to find out if it's up.

However note this also means you have to use the full URL in `cy.visit` and, because the main window is loaded on a random port on localhost (per [the docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Setting-a-global-baseUrl)):

> ...Cypress then switches to the url of the main window to the url
> specified in your visit. This can result in a 'flash' or 'reload' when
> your tests first start.